# Repeater's Item command event is not firing on linkbutton click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having problem with my repeater's OnItemCommand event.
When I click the Link Button, its not firing.
Am I missing any environment variable

ASPX code

```
<table>
    <!-- repResearchers begin, 0=display name, 1=url -->
    <asp:Repeater ID="repExtResearchers" Runat="server" OnItemCommand="deleteResearcher">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="<%# ((System.String[])Container.DataItem)[1] %>">
                    <%# ((System.String[])Container.DataItem)[0] %></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandName="del" 
                    CommandArgument = "<%# ((System.String[])Container.DataItem)[1]%>"
                    OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure do you want to delelte it?')) return false;">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

CS

```
protected void deleteResearcher(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string a;
    lblError.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    lblError.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: does the onClientClick pop up a confirm msg for starters..? are you also registering that Server or Client Side event.. something like this ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: Yes pop up works fine and no I dont have any client side script like that.. Or atleast not from what I understand

Comment: I tested your code and looks fine (the button fires).

Comment: btw you can use this <%# DataBinder.GetIndexedPropertyValue(Container.DataItem,"[0]") %> instead of ((System.String[])Container.DataItem)[0]

Comment: @AdrianIftode thats not a good news :P Now I have no idea where to look

Comment: I know the feeling. Try to use Fiddler to see what it posts back. If something meaningful is posted, try with debugger to see why it jumps the handler.

Comment: When I click on the LinkButton, postback happens but whole repeater disappears

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735777/linkbutton-command-event-seems-to-not-be-firing

Comment: @jrummell I am not using AJAX.. Its just regular repeater and linkbutton

Comment: @AdrianIftode its on default, so its true I believe.. Enabled manually but still no change

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Here disappeared also when viewstate was disabled.

Comment: lol.. thanks for all your help. I learned a lot even though the problem remains.. something will come out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you dont rebind the repeater at every postback.

```
If (Page.IsPostBack)
    return;

repExtResearchers.DataSource = ...
repExtResearchers.DataBind();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: nope...
I already have that safeguard
if (!this.IsPostBack)
    InitializePage(); 
 The whole binding code is in the function

Comment: passing the repeater to a method and binding the arraylist to the repeater there

Comment: Looks like either the repeater items are not being saved in the viewstate or there's something with the data you are binding to.
Also are you sure that there's nothing else which could rebind your repeater at postback?

Comment: yeah.. did a full step by step debug. There is no rebind. I can see the data fine on the page so I dont think data could be a problem.
Most probably its the viewstate but still not sure

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure - as this is an EXTREMELY old question - that this has been answered already, but for people who may be running into what I was running into...

If you're using any of the Ajax Controls, they all require a validation group. I had a really long page that I was trying to shorten by doing this, so I wasn't noticing that the ajax controls from the Ajax Control Toolkit were throwing errors and not validating. I set the LinkButton's validation group to something that was nowhere anywhere and it started firing.

Hopefully, that helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

It won't fix your ptoblem but change

`OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure do you want to delelte it?')) return false;"`

to

`OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure do you want to delelte it?')"`

Your code is using a double negative to confirm a positive.

Comment: Thanks .. changed it.. Now I wish the event fire so I can use the pop up *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using `OnCommand` in a `LinkButton` and I had an empty `href=""`. When I removed the extra attribute, it posted back.