# repeater linkbutton not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, repeater, linkbutton

I have a repeater and inside it a linkbutton, the repeater is bound to OnItemCommand but the event is not firing here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_OnItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptList_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" 
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID").ToString() %>' CommandName="NameClick">  
                    </asp:LinkButton><br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblCreateDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreateDate") %>' /><br />
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

here is the code behind:

```
protected void rptList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "NameClick":
                    Guid id = (Guid)e.CommandArgument;

                    //do something
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: See the answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167535/repeaters-item-command-event-is-not-firing-on-linkbutton-click

Comment: did add the postback but still same thing

Comment: now it does fire but i get System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. on Guid id = (Guid)e.CommandArgument;....if I cast to string is fine

Comment: Try this instead - Guid id = new Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

Comment: nice now it is fine...post it as answer please

Comment: one other thing my page is inside a tab and the event doesnt get fired there but if i manually go to url it is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ram S comment you need to make sure you are not rebinding the repeater on postback (see this question [Repeater's Item command event is not firing on linkbutton click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167535/repeaters-item-command-event-is-not-firing-on-linkbutton-click))

You will also have a problem casting a Guid in that way - change this line of code

```
Guid id = (Guid)e.CommandArgument;
```

To this

```
Guid id = new Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```