# Repeater Linkbutton Onclick not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I am having problem with the LinkButton onclick event not firing.

I have checked the following posts and taken the precaution of Postback but still joy

[repeater linkbutton not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136651/repeater-linkbutton-not-firing)

[Repeater's Item command event is not firing on linkbutton click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167535/repeaters-item-command-event-is-not-firing-on-linkbutton-click)

Here is my Code so far

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phOrders">
<asp:Repeater ID="rprOrders" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rprOrders_ItemCommand">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOrderByDate" runat="server" Text="Date" CommandName="OrderDate" OnClick="lnkOrderByDate_Click"></asp:LinkButton></th>
        <th>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOrderByOrderNumber" runat="server" Text="Order Number"></asp:LinkButton></th>
        <th>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOrderByProductNumber" runat="server" Text="Product Number"></asp:LinkButton></th>
        <th>Product Description</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><strong><%# Eval("OrderDate") %></strong></td>
      <td><%# Eval("OrderNumber") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("SKUNumber") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("OrderItemSKUName") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("mtrx_Code2") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("OrderItemUnitCount") %></td>
      <td><strong><%# Eval("OrderItemStatus") %></strong></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<div class="track-footer"></div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void SetupControl()
{
  if (this.StopProcessing)
  {
    // Do not process
  }
  else
  {
    if (CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite)
    {      
      if(!Page.IsPostBack)
      {            
        PopulateProductClass();
        PopulateProduct();
        PopulateDefaultViewOrders();
      }
    }
  }
}

protected void lnkOrderByDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do Something
}
```

Any suggestions? I can't seem to figure it out?

Even the `OnItemCommand="rprOrders_ItemCommand"` wont fire either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use some thing like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="MyUpdate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("erid") %>'>LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

### .cs

```
    protected void Repeater1_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("MyUpdate"))
    {
        // some code
    }

    if (e.CommandName.Equals("EditCategory"))
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the above and still no triggering from the Event :(

Comment: Make sure you dont rebind the repeater at every postback

Comment: Excellent found the issue. I was rebinding the repeater at postback. Method `PopulateDefaultViewOrders()` contains the code for binding data to the repeater. So once I took the method outside the `if(!Page.IsPostBack) { } ` the ItemCommand got triggered.

Comment: Do I need to bind the repeater inside `if(!Page.IsPostBack){ }`?

Comment: Bind it in page load and then after you invoke the item's command.

Comment: please remember to click "mark as answer" If this answer is correct Thanx :)

Answer (score 4):

The `LinkButton` within your DataControl triggers the Method `rprOrders_ItemCommand`

Set a breakpoint there. If you have multiple `LinkButton` then you can read `CommandName="OrderDate"` Codebehind: `(e.CommandName)`

For passing values `CommandArgument` should be used.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I set a breakpoint as suggested however the Item command `rprOrders_ItemCommand` is also not triggering. :(

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to set `EnableViewState="true"` the the control tag of my ascx file.

E.G.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Settings.ascx.cs" Inherits="Foo.Bar.Settings" EnableViewState="true" %>
```

And my LinkButton looks like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemoveMedia" 
                runat="server" 
                class="icon mdi-delete" 
                OnCommand="btnRemoveMedia_OnCommand" 
                CommandArgument="<%# ((Tuple<int, string>) Container.DataItem).Item1 %>" 
                CommandName="Delete" 
                UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```